# How can I include node modules in Shopware app compiled javascript?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I have a Shopware app I would like to submit to the store. The app uses some third party node modules (socket-io). However whenever I build the javascript, the compiled file in the dist folder of the app does not include my dependencies. When installing this app to a store I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')
```

Locally running `bin/build-storefront.sh` with the app activated fixes the issue, but not by including the dependecy javascript in the compiled js in my app's dist folder. I guess it includes it in the main shopware js file.
How can I have the node modules included properly?

I found the below issue which seems to be the same:
https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-15942

Answer (score 1):

Please see the guide on [adding NPM dependencies](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/using-npm-dependencies).

Comment: No, this does not work. I thought maybe it's something with my specific setup but I tried the exact example with missionlog (with a separate new app) and getting the same error. 
Maybe it's something different when using apps instead of plugins?

Comment: Correction to my initial assessment. It looks like the build process DOES include my dependecies in the dist js file. For both socket io and missionlog scenarios. But still there is something wrong with the compiled file that throws the error.

Comment: have you ever found a solution, please?